# Stop recur mails from sending out to users

Tags: extension, email, recurring-contributions

Current civi behaviour is that whenever a recurring payment is made using a contribution page, two emails are sent.

- Contribution Receipt AND
- Recurring start notification.

Now, when the next scheduled date occurs, a contribution is recorded which additionally send an email to the user notifying about the recur payment.

We don't want this recur start, periodic emails and the end notification to be sent by CiviCRM.

We've written a small extension which is able to stop the start and end notification. Is there an existing way to stop periodic recur e-mails?

CiviCRM version 4.7.29.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such way to stop recurring notification being send out from CiviCRM. Current code at line 567 in [CRM/Contribute/BAO/ContributionPage.php](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Contribute/BAO/ContributionPage.php#L567) checks for $isEmailReceipt which is either set using is_email_receipt of contribution page or if recurring is recorded offline.

Two ways of handling this:

1. Change in core :

   - Add checkbox field on payment processor form 'Notify user about
     recurring payments?'
   - Change code at line 567 in
     [CRM/Contribute/BAO/ContributionPage.php](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Contribute/BAO/ContributionPage.php#L567) to check if 'Notify user
     about recurring payments?' is TRUE.
2. Through extension:

   - Add checkbox field on payment processor form 'Notify user about
     recurring payments?' using [buildForm](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) hook and store value in 
     extension custom table.
   - Using [alterMailParams](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterMailParams/) hook abort the email if 'Notify user about
     recurring payments?' is true for the payment processor used and Message template == Recurring Noification.

Comment: Hey Pradeep, Thanks for posting. Not sure, but it seems the above code will get called for recurring start and end notification only? If yes, I've handled this case by aborting `contribution_recurring_notify` template from alterMailParam hook. But, the periodic emails do get sent after the scheduled payment is done. Seems they use the normal contribution receipt template? Just throwing hard guesses ;-)

Comment: contribution_recurring_notify gets send for first and last payment of contribution recur. For subsequent payments the normal online or offline receipt for contribution or membership message template is used to send which has recurring details i guess.